# Request to reopen question on 'Which framework'

Tags: support, reopen-closed

This question was closed as not constructive, long ago:

[Which JavaScript framework should I use for a Cordova project?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12733718/1761793)

I have edited the question and added some additional factors to consider while answering it. I think that the question is answerable and can be reopened. Or does it need more work?

Comment: That still reads mostly like a library recommendation.  And the question is still very broad.  I think it will be really hard to edit this question into something that is on-topic.

Comment: How can I improve it? Should I remove "Other factors"?

Comment: @Ajoy It should just be deleted.  There's no real way to transform that into a question appropriate for SO.

Comment: I am trying to open the question because I believe it can be answered. Wrt the three frameworks, small applications can use backbone, as it is lightweight, etc, bigger applications need more abstractions, less boilerplate and so on

Comment: And yet the question is unquestionably out of scope on SO.

Comment: @Ajoy questions on pizza toppings can be answered, just not on SO.

Comment: Tonight, I'm going with extra pepperoni, jalapenos and habanero sauce.

Comment: You should use Ionic; It wraps cordova and uses Angular.  It also has its own CSS and Icons: ionicframework.com http://www.slideshare.net/gortok/building-cross-platform-mobile-apps-quickly-with-ionic

Comment: My bad! After all these years at SO, I always interpreted too broad as 'can be narrowed'. I get it now!

Comment: @Ajoy Sometimes questions that appear to be too broad _can_ be narrowed. This just wasn't a particularly great example of one of those. Don't let that discourage you from editing stuff you _think_ could be useful and fit within the topic scope going forward.

Comment: @TimPost It won't! I always edit posts to either improve readability or fix errors. I just learned that this question fell under 'recommending a tool'. Its a thin line, but will help me view other questions more discreetly!

Comment: @GeorgeStocker dolla dolla bills yall

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe it should not be reopened, because it falls under some of the current close reasons: off-topic as tool recommendation, and too broad.

> *off-topic*:
>   Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.
>
> *too broad*
>   There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be
>   too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set
>   or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: Also primarily opinion based, but then again that off-topic reason is really just a special case of primarily opinion based.